# Configure Access-Control-Allow-Origin for monit

Tags: monit

I am trying to grab json data from monit and display it on a status page for management to see the current status of a handful of processes.  This info would be displayed in Confluence running on the same machine but since Confluence (apache) and monit are running on different ports it is considered to be cross domain.
I know I can write a server side process to serve this data but that seems to be overkill and would actually take longer that it took to set monit up in the first place :)
The simplest solution is to configure monit's headers (Access-Control-Allow-Origin) to allow the other server.  Does anyone know how to do this?  I suspect there is a way since M/Monit would run into the same issue.  I have tried some blind attempts on the "httpd... allow" lines but it complains about the syntax with x.x.x.x:port or using keyword "port" in that location.

Answer (score 1):

ok... going to answer my own question (sort of).
First, I think I may have asked the question wrong.  I don't deal with a lot of cross domain issues.  Sorry about that.

But here is what I did to get to the monit info from the other servers:  pretty simple using proxies in apache where the main server is:

```
ProxyPass /monit http://localhost:2812
ProxyPassReverse /monit http://mainserver/monit

ProxyPass /monit2 http://server2:2812
ProxyPassReverse /monit2 http://mainserver/monit2
```

I did this for each of the servers and tested that I can get to either the monit web interface or to the _status?format=json sub pages.  I can now call them using ajax on our main web page.

This also has the benefit that I can lock down the monit access control to just the main server but have the info show on a more visible page.  :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you would need a proxy to just display monit's api or http info. It depends on how you have your network and dns configured. If you'd like to use only localhost, then that might be necessary. But, monit does have a facility to use global host ip access using allow directives in it's own config rc file